# How to run multiple functions in a class simultaneously

Tags: python, function, class

I am trying to get 5 functions in a class to run simultaneously because one of them has an infinite loop, and another has a very long process. This is a sample of the code. I use a python3.5

```
import datetime
import time


class Dan:

    def func1(self):
        curtime = ''
        newtime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        if newtime != curtime:
            curtime = newtime
            print(curtime)
        time.sleep(1)
        Dan.func1(self)

    def func2(self):
        while True:
            print(datetime.date.today())
            time.sleep(1)
            Dan.func2(self)
Dan()
```

Comment: It looks like both methods `func1` and `func2` are not infinite loops but rather infinite recursions with no returns. That is bad practice, especially in Python which has a fairly low limit on recursion depth (1000) and does not do tail recursion optimization. You should rewrite those into actual infinite loops with some stopping condition. As for your question, research `threads` in Python.

Comment: There are two approaches to this: os-level [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html) and using a single thread with [time scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sched.html) (or generally speaking, event scheduling)